# SQL subqueries/ subqueries within subqueries

Tags: sql

I'm trying to learn SQL (through a company guide). 
I have a list of invoices in a table and a tax code associated with one. 
All of the invoices have one tax code, except number 1000001 which has two (and therefore two records in dbo.InvoiceTaxBreakDown.

The exercise wants me to create the variables TaxCode1 and TaxCode2. All except one record should have 'NULL' in TaxCode2.

This is my code:

```
SELECT
   InvoiceNo,
   TaxCode1 = 
   (
      SELECT
         TOP 1 T.TaxCode 
      FROM
         dbo.InvoiceTaxBreakDown as T 
      WHERE
         I.InvoiceGUID = T.InvoiceGUID 
      ORDER BY
         T.TaxCode DESC
   )
,
   TaxCode2 = 
   (
      SELECT
         TOP 1 T.TaxCode 
      FROM
         dbo.InvoiceTaxBreakDown as T 
      WHERE
         I.InvoiceGUID = T.InvoiceGUID 
      ORDER BY
         T.TaxCode ASC
   )
FROM
   dbo.InvoiceTaxBreakDown as I

I'm not sure if I even need to reference two data sources..

Only the first record is correct! Please help.
[Output][1]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Show sample data and the values for the 2 tax codes. Your subqueries should have in the `Where` clause the values of each tax code for their respective `TaxCode1` and `TaxCode2` columns.